# How do I run a Python script on a processing server?

Tags: python, architecture, server

I have written my Python script to take an inputted argument via command line.

My script simply take a URL (inputted via command line), then runs the script; which counts how many lines of HTML code is on the URL page. Its a very simple script.

I would like to put this script on my website. If you click a button on my webpage, the URL of my webpage is sent to the script, then it process the information, and returns it to my website.

How would I be able to do this? What would the back-end architecture look like? How can I increase my processing speeds? Will my script be able to process multiple clicks from different users simultaneously?

Comment: Also, if you have any good reads on the topic, please provide them.

Comment: Learn about the [Python WebFramework](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#newwindow=1&safe=strict&q=Python+WebFramework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could do this. The first and the simplest would be [CGI or Common Gateway Interface](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm). The second would be a [python web framework](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) like flask or django , which you could configure via wgsi so like you said, it would run when it's url is accessed.